# columns headings vertically - crossbw

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, rotation

I have to draw a table with many columns. In order to make the table
fit into the screen, I have decided to print the column headings vertically.

How to implement a cross-browser solution for the output of vertical
headers? Browsers: IE6+, FF3.0+, Opera 9.5+, Chrome 4.0+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.tableClass th {

writing-mode: tb-rl;

filter: fliph() flipV();

}
```

For cross browser implementation use jQuery.
Have a look on this SO discussion.
[Vertical text inside table headers using a JavaScript-based SVG library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705174/vertical-text-inside-table-headers-using-a-javascript-based-svg-library)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle demonstrating the use of CSS3 Transform: http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippeVay/hXnsT/
IE has its own rotating property (with 90° steps, that would be OK for your needs here), but I didn't included it in the fiddle because the origin of rotation isn't the same than for CSS3 transform.

This fiddle was an answer to [How to create vertical table heading text with html5 canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811755/how-to-create-vertical-table-heading-text-with-html5-canvas). The other solution from @dev-null-dweller uses [canvas](http://jsfiddle.net/dev_null_dweller/qyfyb/), so you'll have to consider old IE separately. One thing that lacks in its solution is original text. The text should be put in a span or div and moved out of the viewport with `text-indent: -9999px; position: absolute;`. That way screen readers will still read the textual content to their users (canvas isn't accessible yet)